# Sub-breeds in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo and I have some questions about the following piece of code:

```
people-own [
  walker-type   ;; can be "cautious", "adaptive" or "reckless"
  walked-through-red?
  own-profit
  adaptive-threshold-time-gained
  adaptive-threshold-time-gained-people-crossing
  adaptive-gone-reckless
  cooldown
]
```

With an OO background, I see this as some kind of enumeration of the properties of an object (the `people` breed). You can clearly see that there are three types of people: cautious walkers, adaptive walkers and reckless walkers. Also, the properties beginning with `adaptive` (`adaptive-threshold-time-gained` and such) have only meaning when the current person is `adaptive`.

I would expect that there is some way to express this more elegantly. In an OO programming language you would use inheritance to create three subclasses (one for each `walker-type`), but for so far I know that doesn't exist in NetLogo.

What is the recommended way of expressing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lack of inheritance (perhaps as sub-breeds) is a serious limitation of NetLogo, although in the end it has only occasionally mattered to me.  There are a couple possible work-arounds, depending on the application.

1. If you just want some different data attributes, and the related types are the only `turtles` in the simulation, you can have `turtles-own` the common characteristics and have `breeds-own` only the type specific characteristics.
2. If the data attributes are all shared but the behavior differs, you can create your own agentsets (in your case, subsets of `people`) and call different procedures on each agent set (or write procedures that branch on a `member?` test).  Unfortunately, these agentsets will have to be explicitly augmented if any new members are created, so you lose that nice "special agentset" feature of breeds.

hth.